# How to share and automatically update my Stack Overflow answers at my blog/LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter?

Tags: feature-request

I know there is a share function for Stack Overflow questions/answers, but I need to copy the share link to my blog/LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter manually. I hate that and want it automatic.

I don't want to write a tool automatically to catch the share URL then paste into my blog/LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter automatically.

I just want JavaScript code like Google Maps, Google analysis. I just need to put it at my blog/LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter. Then it will automatically list my newest Stack Overflow questions/answers without any operations. It does save my time.

Comment: So you're basically looking for some kind of integration between [main] and 3rd-party sites like Facebook and Twitter, where your [main] activity is automatically posted to those social networks, correct? The [se] doesn't have anything like that built-in that I'm aware of, but someone might have built a plugin for it over at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) or something.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for  integration between Stack Overflow and 3rd-party sites like Facebook and Twitter.

Answer (score 8):

[If This Then That](https://ifttt.com) can probably help you here.

Essentially, it is a service that acts as a bridge between different web services.

So, for instance, you could use your [user feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/2769693) (which you can find in the lower right of your user profile page) in the [Feed Channel](https://ifttt.com/feed) and trigger off of a new item, setting your Action (the "That") to be whatever is appropriate: [Facebook](https://ifttt.com/facebook), [Twitter](https://ifttt.com/twitter), etc.

For instance, here's [a recipe that Tweets someone's Stack Overflow activity](https://ifttt.com/recipes/10488-when-i-stackoverflow-then-twitter-it). You can modify it to your purposes.

In fact, there are quite a few [Stack Overflow recipes](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=stack+overflow&ac=false).